# setting initial parameters for scipy.differential_evolution

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization, differential-evolution

In a [differential evolution](http://www1.icsi.berkeley.edu/~storn/code.html) optimization algorithm from [scipy](https://www.scipy.org/), is it possible to set initial parameters if I have some good starting points?

For example, suppose i know the best `x` is `[0.1, 0.5,0.3]`, is it possible to add it inside `scipy.differential_evolution`

Answer (score 0):

The [`scipy.optimize.differential_evolution`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.1.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.differential_evolution.html#scipy.optimize.differential_evolution) function has two parameters you can work with:

1. > `bounds : sequence`
   >
   > Bounds for variables. `(min, max)` pairs for each element in `x`, defining the lower and upper bounds for the optimizing argument of *func*. [CUT]

   You could try:

   ```
   >>> bounds = [(0.0, 0.2), (0.4, 0.6), (0.2, 0.4)]
   >>> result = differential_evolution(my_func, bounds)
   ```
2. **Recent versions** of the library (from SciPy v1.1.0) allow to specify which type of population initialization is performed via the `init` keyword:

   > `init : str or array-like, optional`
   >
   > Specify which type of population initialization is performed. Should be one of:
   >
   > - ‘latinhypercube’
   > - ‘random’
   > - array specifying the initial population. The array should have shape `(M, len(x))`, where `len(x)` is the number of parameters. `init` is clipped to bounds before use.
   >
   > [CUT]
   >
   > Use of an array to specify a population subset could be used, for example, to create a tight bunch of initial guesses in an location where the solution is known to exist, thereby reducing time for convergence.